# Webpack & bundling of required files?

Tags: javascript, webpack

Just getting started with webpack. One of the first things i've noticed is webpack will walk your dependency graph (in my case with required statements) and embedded everything into one huge file. For example if i have `myjsfile.js` that requires `lodash.js`. It will be outputed as one file. This is not what i was expecting and probably not what i want either. I guess i was expecting webpack to just load the required dependencies at runtime. So if i referenced `myjsfile.js` at runtime it would also download `lodash.js` without me specifically having to reference it on the page. I, of course, don't want one huge js file per page. That would kill caching for one. Any clarification of how this all works would be appreciated.

Comment: https://webpack.github.io/docs/code-splitting.html

Answer (score 0):

Check out [commons chunk plugin](http://jonathancreamer.com/advanced-webpack-part-1-the-commonschunk-plugin/). Something like this:

```
entry: {
  app: './js/app.js',
  vender: ['lodash', 'jquery'],
},
```

A tool like [html-webpack-plugin](https://github.com/ampedandwired/html-webpack-plugin) can help you auto include scripts.

webpack 2 (still a beta version at this point) [supports load on demand from System.import](http://moduscreate.com/code-splitting-for-react-router-with-es6-imports/).

```
System.import('./pathTo/' + moduleName).then(doCallback);
```

Comment: I looked into this? Wouldn't this require you still but the 'vendor' dependencies into your page manually? So if you have 5 vendor dependencies (that you don't want to merge into one because different dependencies are used on different page) then webpack is not going to help you out because you still have to embed them in the page and in the keep them in the correct order?